# Why does it take so long to execute commands with sudo?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

I have a VM running Kali Linux 2021.3. I have only 2 users `kali` and `root`. The `kali` user possesses sudo permissions with a password. When I run a command without sudo permission, it executes fine. But when I execute the same command with sudo permissions, it takes at least **more than 20 seconds to prompt me for the password**

But when I switch the user to root with `su root` and run commands, this doesn't happen. Additionally, programs like **python and PHP take longer** than usual to get executed.
For example, to start a simple HTTP server with python: `python3 -m http.server 8080` also takes more than 20 seconds.

I thought this was a problem with low RAM. So I tried increasing the RAM by 2GB. It still doesn't work. I **did an upgrade with APT recently**. I wonder if that's what caused this issue. My current version is,

uname -a:

```
Linux kali 5.10.0-kali7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1kali1 (2021-04-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output of the auth.log when I execute the command with sudo

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

```
Oct 23 17:21:27 kali sudo:     kali : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/kali ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls
Oct 23 17:21:27 kali sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Oct 23 17:21:27 kali sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: I wonder is this is a problem with your user configuration. I reinstalled Kali at 2021.1 (for other reasons) and there is no "root" user. My own user runs everything either natively or with sudo and there is no slowness with sudo . My Kali machine is a virtual machine.

Comment: To break up the problem (for troubleshooting), first run `sudo -i` to get into a root prompt, then run your command.  What happens?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the /etc/hosts file. I didn't have an entry for my hostname(kali). I just added an entry in my host files as:

```
kali   127.0.0.1
```

I found about this from this post.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/322514/terminal-command-with-sudo-takes-a-long-time